# External Network Adapter Location Domain instead of Public

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012, windows-firewall

Running a Windows 2012 Server as a DC/DNS/DHCP/RRAS (NAT) in a 2 nic environment where 1 is public and one is private. Server sees both nics as part of the domain... this is quite unpleasant since I would like to take advantage of the different firewall profiles.

Do you have any ideas what I could do to force the adapter to be seen as public? Changing settings in GPO/LPO didn't have any effect, I'm still unable to change the location... I'm guessing NLA has something to do with it too...

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing would be to open the Network and Sharing Center, then set the apdapter (under active networks) to be a public network instead of work/private.  Once you've done that then set the firewall rules as needed for the public network.

Comment: Ya... if you can show me how to do that on a domain controller running Windows 2012 I'll give you money.

Comment: Did you ever solve that problem? I just ran into the same situation =/